# Generating a Sample T-Distribution in Python

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, probability

I'm new to DataScience. I'm going through the stats module and the ways to create a sample T-distribution.

Using the below line to generate the sample. However, my question is how is the array calculated just by providing the degree of freedom and the sample size parameter.

I understand the calculation of T-scores when a sample set is provided and also the rationale of the T-distribution and other concepts. I would like to know how the below output is returned just by providing the degree of freedom.

I found an equation of the probability density function for the t distribution in the below documentation. Is that the equation used for the calculation?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.standard_t.html#numpy.random.RandomState.standard_t

```
t_dist = np.random.standard_t(20, size=5)

t_dist
```

> Output:array([-0.08635068, -0.45353444, -0.02419345, -0.16954368,  0.49006959]).

Having posting the query in ChatGPT, it provided the below line of code as one of the step in the t-sample creation. But, not sure how the Chi-square distribution is involved.

```
t_sample = standard_normal / np.sqrt(np.random.chisquare(df, sample_size) / df)
```

Comment: please provide the code, some code is missing. t-dist is related to chi-square dist.